# Avoiding to call the __init__ of a Mixin class several times

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I'm working on a large structure which is working with a Mixin to register function handles of classes to a central element which provides an API to an end-user. I now have 2 different hardware setups which in general are very similar and have a very large common subset of functions, but both of them have additional functions to register.

So I put the common subset of functionality into an abstract base class ("Bar" in the following example) which inherits from the Mixin. Both the hardware classes ("Foo" and "Foo2") inherit from "Bar" but also from the Mixin, which leads to a double call of Mixin.**init**() during the initialization phase of either "Foo" or "Foo2"

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
import inspect


class FunctionHandler:
    function_register = dict()

    @staticmethod
    def register_function(stuff, register):
        if register not in FunctionHandler.function_register.keys():
            FunctionHandler.function_register[register] = list()

        FunctionHandler.function_register[register].append(stuff)


class Mixin(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        ABC.__init__(self)
        # only call mix in the highest level of inheritance
        if not inspect.stack()[2].function == "__init__":
            self.mix()

    @abstractmethod
    def mix(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def register_stuff(self, stuff, register):
        FunctionHandler.register_function(stuff, register)


class Bar(Mixin, ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        ABC.__init__(self)
        self.name = "bar"
        Mixin.__init__(self)

    def mix(self):
        # register a lot of stuff common to all inheriting classes
        self.register_stuff("bar", self.name)
        self.register_stuff("bar2", self.name)


class Foo(Bar, Mixin):
    def __init__(self):
        Bar.__init__(self)
        self.name = "foo"

        Mixin.__init__(self)

    def mix(self):
        Bar.mix(self)
        self.register_stuff("foo", self.name)


class Foo2(Bar, Mixin):
    def __init__(self):
        Bar.__init__(self)
        self.name = "foo2"

        Mixin.__init__(self)

    def mix(self):
        Bar.mix(self)
        self.register_stuff("foo2", self.name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo = Foo()
    foo2 = Foo2()

    print(FunctionHandler.function_register)
```

My desired result for this example is:

```py
{'foo': ['bar', 'bar2', 'foo'], 'foo2': ['bar', 'bar2', 'foo2']}
```

Double initialization of this Mixin leads to unnecessary entries in the function register which i would like to avoid.

My current solution is, to only call self.mix() of the Mixin if the calling class is at the very top of the inheritance (for classes which are not base classes of another child) with the inspect.stack() condition:

```py
if not inspect.stack()[2].function == "__init__":
    self.mix()
```

As you can check, the result without this condition is:

```py
{'foo2': ['bar', 'bar2', 'foo2'], 'foo': ['bar', 'bar2', 'foo'], 'bar': ['bar', 'bar2', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar2', 'foo2']}
```

So in general my solution works, however i'm not completely satisfied with it, as a string comparison condition on the call stack seems a bit unsafe to me.

So for me there are 2 questions:

1. Is my concept not optimal such that this double Mixin.**init**() call happens in the first place? If yes, how could this structure be implemented in a better way?
2. If the concept in general is ok, is there a way to check the "inheritance depth" such that i could check on this, instead of the function name of the call stack?

Comment: You should be using `super()` instead of hardcoding the reference to `ABC`. You also don't need any subclass of `Bar` to inherit from `Mixin` directly; such classes already inherit from `Mixin`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with the double call to `Mixin.__init__()`, but that in this method there is the `mix()` method, so it got called 2 times instead of 1 (cause Bar calls it, and then Foo and Foo2 call it again).

To remove this behaviour, it's better to call `mix()` inside the leaves classes, so the`Foo.__init__()` and `Foo2.__init__()` methods should look like this:

```
class Mixin(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        ABC.__init__(self)
        # end of __init__

class Foo(Bar, Mixin):
    def __init__(self):
        Bar.__init__(self)
        self.name = "foo"
        Mixin.__init__(self)
        self.mix()

    def mix(self):
        Bar.mix(self)
        self.register_stuff("foo", self.name)
```

The result is the same as you wanted:

`{'foo': ['bar', 'bar2', 'foo'], 'foo2': ['bar', 'bar2', 'foo2']}`

---

**EDIT**
If you want to leave the mix method inside `Mixin.__init__()`, you could pass an object argument to the constructor and call mix() on it.

```
class Mixin(ABC):
    def __init__(self, obj=None):
        ABC.__init__(self)
        if obj and isinstance(obj, Mixin):
            obj.mix()

class Foo(Bar, Mixin):
    def __init__(self):
        Bar.__init__(self)
        self.name = "foo"
        Mixin.__init__(self, self)
```

The output it's still the same

Comment: This would obviously work, however the Mixin is used for a variety of different modules (number increasing) within the system. So I'd prefer a general solution which does not require to  call the mix function manually on each usage of the Mixin

Comment: Check out my edit and see if it's the behavior you want